# Why can’t I login to StackOverflow using my LJ OpenID?

Tags: support, openid

When I try to login to SO using my LJ openid I get this error:

> Unable to log in with your OpenID provider:
>   No OpenID endpoint found.

I have only one ID assotiated with my account. What can I do to get the account back?

Comment: I have the same issue. Luckily I set up a secondary OpenID a few months ago so I can use that as an alternative.

Comment: I use LJ as my primary (although I'm tempted to kill the journal). Got a couple pages a little earlier which didn't have me logged in.

Comment: Retagging this was it was a LiveJournal bug, not something we can resolve (not directly, you'd have to email to get another OpenID added, or create a new user and request a merge).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Send an email to team@stackoverflow.com.

Make sure you mention your SO userid.